# WPF ComboBox selection change on TabItem selection change

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox, tabs, selecteditem

I have a combobox in a tab item in MVVM. This tab can be created multiple times in my application (same view, same view model but different instance), so I can switch from one tab to another (but they are tab of the same type).

It works perfectly with every WPF control, but with combobox I have a strange behaviour: 
the focus tab, when it loses focus, gets the selected item of the combox box of the tab that the application is focusing on.

If I switch from 2 tabs that are not of the same type everything works correctly, any idea about that? Thanks.

XAML:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="StatusView" Source="{Binding Path=StatusList}"/>
<ComboBox Name="_spl2Status" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatusView}}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentSPL2.ID_SPL2_STATUS, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedValuePath="FL_TYPE"
          DisplayMemberPath="ID_TYPE">
</ComboBox>
```

VM:

```
public List<NullableByteEnumType> StatusList
{
    get
    {
        return (SPC_SPL2.SPL2StatusCollection.Skip(1)).ToList();
    }
}

private SPC_SPL2 _currentSPL2 = null;

public SPC_SPL2 CurrentSPL2
{
    get
    {
        if (_currentSPL2== null)
            Controller.Execute(delegate(IResult result)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                parameters.Add("FL_ACTIVE", true);
                parameters.Add("ID_SPL2", _itemcode);
                Model.Invalidate(typeof(SPC_SPL2), Filter.GENERIC<SPC_SPL2>(parameters, "ID_SPL2"));
                Model.Include<SPC_SPL2>();

                if (Model.Appendload(result) == false)
                    return false;

                Debug.Assert(Context.SPC_SPL2.Count == 1);
                _currentSPL2= Context.SPC_SPL2.FirstOrDefault();

                return result.Successful;
            });

        return _currentSPL2;
    }
    set
    {
        _currentSPL2= value;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => CurrentSPL2);
    }
}
```

my tabs are handled in this way:

```
<Grid>
    <Border Grid.Row="0">
        <ContentControl 
            Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}" 
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MasterWorkspacesTemplate}"
            />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

where

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="MasterWorkspacesTemplate">
            <TabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                        BorderThickness="0" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding}"
                        ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}"
                        />
        </DataTemplate>
```

and workspaces (my viewmodels list) (T is a class who inherit from viewModelBase)

```
 public T CurrentWorkspace
    {
        get { return WorkspacesView.CurrentItem as T; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<T> _workspaces;
    public ObservableCollection<T> Workspaces
    {
        get
        {
            if (_workspaces == null)
            {
                _workspaces = new ObservableCollection<T>();
                _workspaces.CollectionChanged += _OnWorkspacesChanged;
            }

            return _workspaces;
        }
    }
    protected ICollectionView WorkspacesView
    {
        get
        {
            ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Workspaces);
            Debug.Assert(collectionView != null);
            return collectionView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pls, add some code of the view with the `ComboBox` and the bound VM.

Comment: I add some code, thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you show how you initialize the viewmodel, and what MVVM framework are you using?

Comment: This can be a problem of your tab control and how you assign values in the view model.It would be better if you can show us the full xaml and the view model.

Answer (score 1):

I have recreated your problem. But I couldn't find any issue. Please look at the code below and you might get the solustion. Here is my solution.

`MyTab` view model

```
public class MyTab : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Declarations

    private ObservableCollection<string> statusList;
    private string selectedStatus;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the header.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The header.</value>
    public string Header { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the content.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The content.</value>
    public string Content { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the status list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The status list.</value>
    public ObservableCollection<string> StatusList
    {
        get
        {
            return statusList;
        }
        set
        {
            statusList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("StatusList");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the selected status.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The selected status.</value>
    public string SelectedStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedStatus = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedStatus");
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

`MainViewModel` view model

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Declarations

    private ObservableCollection<MyTab> tabs;
    private MyTab selectedTab;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the tabs.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The tabs.</value>
    public ObservableCollection<MyTab> Tabs
    {
        get
        {
            return tabs;
        }
        set
        {
            tabs = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Tabs");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the selected tab.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The selected tab.</value>
    public MyTab SelectedTab
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedTab;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedTab = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedTab");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainViewModel"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Tabs = new ObservableCollection<MyTab>();

        MyTab tab1 = new MyTab();
        tab1.Header = "tab1";
        tab1.Content = "Tab 1 content";
        ObservableCollection<string> tab1StatusList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        tab1StatusList.Add("tab1 item1");
        tab1StatusList.Add("tab1 item2");
        tab1StatusList.Add("tab1 item3");
        tab1.StatusList = tab1StatusList;
        tab1.SelectedStatus = tab1StatusList.First();
        this.Tabs.Add(tab1);

        MyTab tab2 = new MyTab();
        tab2.Header = "tab2";
        tab2.Content = "Tab 2 content";
        ObservableCollection<string> tab2StatusList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        tab2StatusList.Add("tab2 item1");
        tab2StatusList.Add("tab2 item2");
        tab2StatusList.Add("tab2 item3");
        tab2.StatusList = tab2StatusList;
        tab2.SelectedStatus = tab2StatusList.First();
        this.Tabs.Add(tab2);

        this.SelectedTab = tab1;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And finally this is my `XAML`

```
 <Window x:Class="ComboboxSelectedItem.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ComboboxSelectedItem.ViewModels"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Name="mainGrid">

    <Grid.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel />
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <TabControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">

        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Margin="0 0 20 0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

        <!--Content section-->
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock
                            Text="{Binding Content}" />
                        <ComboBox
                            ItemsSource="{Binding StatusList}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStatus}" />
                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: well I found a difference, I add it in my question (re-edited)

Comment: I reproduce the error in a simpler application (so it is easier to upload some code). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531920/wpf-combobox-selection-change-after-switching-tabs thank you in advance in case you'd like to take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that you are creating a new instance of the viewmodel.  If not, then the comboboxes are sharing the same collectionviewsource which means that a change in one combobox will be reflected in all comboboxes.  I had this same problem myself.

Try declaring the collection view source in code:

```
CollectionViewSource StatusListViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
StatusListViewSource.Source = SPL2StatusCollection;
```

then in xaml change binding to the collectionviewsource:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding StatusListViewSource.View}"
```

I converted from vb so it might need some edits.
Does that help?

Comment: I still have the same error. and I'm sure they are different instance since when I load them they took the correct data (different) from a DB, but when I switch tab, they copy the data (and I check that the problem is not on the load, but on the tab change)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where to go from here.  I usually start steping through at every procedure to find out what is going on.  Can you check to see what is happening in the underlying binding.  Maybe it is a UI issue where the data is okay in the viewmodel but the UI is wrong.  Are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?