# WPF ComboBox selection change after switching tabs

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, tabs

I made a project based on nested tabs.
the nested tabs are different instance of the same viemModel and the same UI. 
when I switch between the tabs he comboboxes present in the tabs chenge thei selection depending on the tab that is loosing focus.

I add both the viewmodels and the view of my test project.
thank you in advance for your help

main window

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:IntermediateViewModel}">
        <local:IntermediateView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderedTabItemTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter
                        Content="{Binding Path=Header, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            </ContentPresenter>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="SimpleTabItemStyle" TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#555959">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 ContentSource="Header" Margin="12,2,12,2" RecognizesAccessKey="True" Height ="40" MinWidth ="90"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#555959" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTabControlTemplate">
        <TabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                        BorderThickness="0" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderedTabItemTemplate}"
                        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SimpleTabItemStyle}"
                        SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged"
                        />
    </DataTemplate>


    <!---->


</Window.Resources>

<Grid MinHeight="200" MinWidth="300">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="260*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="51*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border >
        <ContentControl 
            Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}" 
            ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource DefaultTabControlTemplate}"
             />
    </Border>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

view model (create a different istance each time)

```
class MainWindowViewModel : WorkspacesViewModel<IntermediateViewModel>
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.WorkspacesView.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(WorkspacesView_CurrentChanged);
    }

    void WorkspacesView_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    RelayCommand myVar = null;
    public ICommand AddCommand
    {
        get 
        {
            return myVar ?? (myVar = new RelayCommand(param => 
            {
                SetWindow(new IntermediateViewModel("AA" + this.Workspaces.Count) );
            })); 
        }
    }
```

first level tab

```
    <UserControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ClassViewModel}">
        <local:ClassView />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Border>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentWorkspace, Mode=OneWay}" Loaded="ContentControl_Loaded" DataContextChanged="ContentControl_DataContextChanged" IsVisibleChanged="ContentControl_IsVisibleChanged" LayoutUpdated="ContentControl_LayoutUpdated" TargetUpdated="ContentControl_TargetUpdated" Unloaded="ContentControl_Unloaded" />
</Border>
```

first level viewmodel

class IntermediateViewModel : WorkspacesViewModel
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }

```
    public IntermediateViewModel(string header)
    {
        Header = header;
        SetWindow(new ClassViewModel(header));
    }
}
```

nested tab

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="StatusView" Source="{Binding Path=StatusList}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Name="_spl2Status" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatusView}}"
      SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      SelectedValuePath="FL_TYPE"
      DisplayMemberPath="ID_TYPE" Margin="76,12,0,0" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="146"
               DataContextChanged="_spl2Status_DataContextChanged"
               IsVisibleChanged="_spl2Status_IsVisibleChanged"
               Loaded="_spl2Status_Loaded"
                SelectionChanged="_spl2Status_SelectionChanged"
               >
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

nested tab view model

```
public enum myTypes
{ 
    tipo0 = 0,
    tipo1 = 1,
    tipo2 = 2,
}

class ClassViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    public ClassViewModel(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    private List<IntEnumType> _statusList = null;
    public List<IntEnumType> StatusList
    {
        get
        {
            if (_statusList == null)
                _statusList = new List<IntEnumType>()
                {
                    new IntEnumType((int)myTypes.tipo0, myTypes.tipo0.ToString()),
                    new IntEnumType((int)myTypes.tipo1, myTypes.tipo1.ToString()),
                    new IntEnumType((int)myTypes.tipo2, myTypes.tipo2.ToString()),
                };
            return _statusList;
        }
    }

    private int myVar = 1;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get 
        {
            return myVar; 
        }
        set 
        {
            if (myVar != value)
            {
                myVar = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => MyProperty);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class TabItemStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public Style MainTabItem { get; set; }
    public Style ChildrenTabItem { get; set; }
    public Style SpecificationTabItem { get; set; }

    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        //if (item is IHome)
        //    return MainTabItem;
        //else if (item is SpecificationItemViewModel)
        //    return SpecificationTabItem;
        //else
            return ChildrenTabItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is a little hard to completely follow, but I'm guessing that the issue is that there is only one instance of your `ClassViewModel` and it is where the selection for the combo box is stored `{Binding Path=MyProperty`, so whatever is stored in `MyProperty` will be reflected in all instances of the combo box regardless of where they live.

Comment: no, there are 2 viewmodels.. If a have a text box with two different values it works, the problem is just with the combobox

Comment: Then please post the 2nd viewmodel.  Both bound to the same SelectedValue or SelectedIndex would explain this behavior.

Comment: added also the other viewmodels

Comment: So if you keep the binding the same and just change the combobox to text box then each text box keeps it's original value?

Comment: exactly... the error is only with combo.. datagrid loading two different collections works fine, everything is fine but comboboxes

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a bit late, but as I'm facing the same issue, I want to share my analysis.

When you change your tabs, you change the DataContext of the current Tab to your other ViewModel and hence also the ItemsSource of your ComboBox.

In case your previously selected Item (SelectedItem) is not contained within the new ItemsSource, the ComboBox fires a SelectionChanged-Event and therefore sets the SelectedIndex to -1.

Altough this default behaviour of the ComboBox might make sense, it's very annoying in many cases.

We've derived an own class from ComboBox, handling that. But it's not very satisfying as you loose some default behaviour you most probably need.

Comment: @Pille- your answer is helpful to understand the problem. Is there any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your loaded event handlers.

When you switch tabs your unloading one tab and loading a new one.

I suspect your changing `MyComboBox.SelectedIndex` in `_spl2Status_Loaded`.