# Why pressing tab changes the item selected in a combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have 2 **ComboBoxes** which have data inside. When I write some letters of the name of the item in the **first** ComboBox then I press Tab key, focus moves to next control but the item displayed is different from what was before pressing the Tab key. In the **Second** ComboBox the data is related to the selected item in the first, but the retrieved data is based on the item selected before tab which is not displayed. ***My question is : Why did this happen ? How to solve this problem?***

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but it's the only question I found matching my scenario and I found a solution that works to my satisfaction.

What's *essentially* happening is that in a Winforms application ComboBox the tab key goes around finalizing your selection and just moves to the next control. So your ComboBox ends up being thrown back to what appears to be a random item in the selection list. What appears to be the intended flow here is to find your item, click it or hit Enter, then hit tab. So I got around this by overriding ProcessCmdKey on the Form owning the ComboBox to force the Tab key to behave as Enter as long as the ComboBox is dropped down.

Here is an example of what I settled on:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        if (this.youComboBox.DroppedDown && keyData == Keys.Tab)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to set the combobox DropDownStyle to DropDownList instead of DropDown.

If this isn't exactly what you were searching for, please try these ones as well:

[WPF ComboBox selection change after switching tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531920/wpf-combobox-selection-change-after-switching-tabs)
http://www.telerik.com/forums/combobox-value-changes